# Connection through socket : sometimes it connects, sometimes it does not

Tags: java, python, sockets

I am trying to implement communication between a client written in Java and a server written in Python, using a socket. If I start separately the server in a terminal then the client, everything works fine. To make things simpler, I would like the client to trigger the launch of the server, which I did with

```
 try {
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python server.py");
 } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

What is surprising is that now, half of the times I launch the client, everything still works fine, and the other half I get "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect", the repartition between both halves appearing to be completely random. I have checked that both client and server are communicating through the same port.
Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked for potential timing issues? The client might be trying to connect before the server is fully started now and then.

Comment: Apparently a comment cannot be accepted as an answer, but this solved my problem, thanks!